# Android Maven Plugin: Choose packages for testcases to be executed

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven

I am executing unit testing of my Android App with Maven on a Jenkins server.

Everything works as expected, but when I want to specify multiple packages for testing the unit tests are not executed anymore. Maybe it's just my misunderstanding of the syntax in the pom.xml? I thought that you could add multiple packages for unit testing.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <test>
                    <createReport>true</createReport>
                    <packages>
<!-- just one package works without problem -->
                        <package>a.b.c</package>
                        <package>a.b.d</package>
                    </packages>
                </test>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adb documentation for executing packages is here : http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsCommand

To run a single test package the syntax is :

```
adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>
```

I don't think there is any way to run multiple test package in a single command line. So, as the maven plugin ought to be a wrapper for adb, I guess it's not possible to achieve what you want.

You may use profiles to run different test packages.

Comment: Thanks, that page gave me the hint I needed. Specifying the different classes to be executed does work.

Comment: You could maybe add that to your answer as a possibility to specify the testcases to execute on a more fine-grained level