# Specifying specific testcases for Android in maven

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven

I had my previous question answered here: [Android Maven Plugin: Choose packages for testcases to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253906/android-maven-plugin-choose-packages-for-testcases-to-be-executed)

So I now specify my testcases like this:

```
<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <test>
                    <createReport>true</createReport>
                    <classes>
                        <class>a.b.c</class>
                        <class>a.b.c2</class>
                        <class>d.e.f</class>
                    </classes></test>
```

When I only execute the first two classes the tests run without a problem.
However, when I add the third class the tests don't work anymore.
The third test on its own runs without problems.

The error I get is this:

> Running tests for specified test
>   classes/methods: [a.b.c,a.b.c2,d.e.f] [INFO] Running instrumentation
>   tests in de.weptun.android.test on 192.168.1.31:5555 (avdName=null)
>   [INFO]   Run started: de.weptun.android.test, 0 tests: [INFO]   Run
>   failed: java.io.IOException: EOF [INFO]   Run ended: 0 ms [INFO]
>   Tests run: 0,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem seems to be the number of classes added.
In my case as soon as it was more than 15 the tests didn't work anymore.

By changing it back to a smaller number the tests run without problem...